# SQL: Delete rows in a table where one field's value is lesser than group average

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

For now, I am first running the following query:

```
select group_name, avg(numeric_field) as avg_value, count(group_name) as n from table_name group by group_name order by n desc;
```

Suppose I get output:

```
group_name     | avg_value | n
----------------------------------------
nice_group_name| 1566.353  | 2034
other_group    | 235.43    | 1390
.
.
.
```

I am then deleting records in each group one by one *manually* using the following query for each group:

```
delete from table_name where group_name = 'nice_group_name' and numeric_field < 1567;
```

Here 1567 is the approximate `avg_value` for `nice_group_name`.

How can I run the second query for all rows of the result of first query *automatically*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
delete from table_name
    where numeric_field < (select avg(t2.numeric_field)
                           from table_name t2
                           where t2.group_name = table_name.group_name
                          );
```

For performance, you want an index on `tablename(group_name, numeric_field)`.

If you have few groups, you might find this more efficient:

```
with a as (
      select group_name, avg(numeric_field) as anf
      from table_name
      group by group_name
     )
delete from table_name
    where numeric_field < (select a.anf from a where a.group_name = table_name.group_name);
```

Comment: I tried this by replacing the `delete` query with a `select`. This takes unacceptably long time. So much that I had to force kill `sqlitebrowser` process and end with a corrupt database image. I had backup though.

Comment: @pii_ke . . . That is not surprising.  On average, you would be deleting half the rows in the table.  It is usually more efficient to recreate the table.  However, that is NOT the query you asked.  You just asked about fixing your `delete` query.  If you want alternative solutions, ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: That's all right. This query took so long that I began to doubt if this was _unnecessarily repeating_ calculation of average for each deletion check. And that large number of deletions is only smaller part of the problem.

Comment: @pii_ke . . . It is repeating the average calculation; however, deletion is expensive. That said, if you have the index and your groups are not very large, that shouldn't be a big issue.  The issue would be if you have just a handful of groups.

Comment: Thanks for the second solution, it worked well for me (in less than 30 secs). My table had about 120,000 rows and 570 groups. The first solution did not finish even in 6 minutes. I had no indexes on the said columns.

Answer (score 0):

If `table_name` has some primary key field (say `id`) then use the following:

```
alter table table_name rename to bak;
create temp table avg_val as
    select group_name as g, avg(numeric_field) as a from bak
    group by group_name;
create table table_name as
    select * from bak where id in (
        select bak.id from
        avg_val join bak on bak.group_name = avg_val.g
        where avg_val.a <= bak.numeric_field
);
```

Check `table_name`. If all has went well you can delete the backed up old table:

```
drop table bak;
```

Briefly, the steps are:

1. Rename the original table
2. Create a temporary table of average value for each group
3. Create a new table with all rows from original table where numeric_field is *not* less than average for that group.
4. delete the renamed original table.